# OnClick in android does not work

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm writing an android code... I have made a menu item ("+") on the top right. I have defined the OnClick for this item as you see in my code but MyApp does not run and says unfortunately stopped. Before that I used

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add:
              //  Toast.makeText(this, "Adding button selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }
```

for when the user clicks on that item and it worked. But I need to know what should I do in this way?! Because after that I want to make layout (Dialog) so that when I push that item that dialog shows and I think I should use this method to do that

myActivity:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    //@Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public boolean onCreateMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void AddOnClick (View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button 1 pressed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/add"
          android:icon="@drawable/plus"
          android:title="Adding"
          android:orderInCategory="50"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:onClick="AddOnClick"
     />
</menu>
```

Where I am wrong?! Is my way for showing dialog right or I should do something else?!
Tnx in advance

Comment: If your app crashes, please post the stack trace

Comment: remove android:onClick in menu, you don't need it

Answer (score 1):

do as follows and remove android:onClick in menu

```
MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.addXml, menu);
```

Comment: return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

Answer (score 0):

the signature is wrong. It should be

```
 public void AddOnClick (MenuItem item)
```

since it is declared inside a MenuItem

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean onCreateMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    return true;
}
```

change like this:

```
public boolean onCreateMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.addXml, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: if you think there's no way that's correct you can try return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

Comment: The return value of `inflate()` is `void`. Your code would not compile. This would, despite the lack of formatting: @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.container, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

Comment: You have shared code is completely wrong you must use Override methods for OptionsMenu i think you first edit your question.